# Validate Wpf datagrid for duplicate using IDataError

Tags: wpf, validation, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a datagrid which binded using ObservableCollection.Now I want to validate for duplicated entries in a cell against my entire collection.Iam using IDataError for validaton .But my problem how to get the Collection in IDataError object .
Edit

my xaml is:

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="dgPurchaseReturnEntry" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
     SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"
         >
<dg:DataGrid.Columns>
   <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                   Width="300"
                   Header="Product Name"
                   SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=Product_Id,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                                                       
                   SelectedValuePath="Product_Id"
                   DisplayMemberPath="Product_Name"                                           
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductDataProvider}}">
        <dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                            Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                            Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="True" />
            </Style>

        </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </dg:DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</dg:DataGrid.Columns>
```

my object is:

```
public class clsPurchaseBillEntryList : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{

    private int _Product_Id;

    #region Property Getters and Setters

    public int Product_Id
    {
        get { return _Product_Id; }
        set
        {
            _Product_Id = value;

            OnPropertyChanged("Product_Id");
        }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    // Declare the event
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //// Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDataErrorInfo Members

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
            // iterate over all of the properties
            // of this object - aggregating any validation errors
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                string propertyError = this[prop.Name];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyError))
                {
                    error.Append(propertyError);
                }
            }
            return error.ToString();
        }
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            string result = null;
            if (name == "Qty")
            {

            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Now How do I get my collection in my validation class that IDataError?

Comment: can you post a code that you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

The ability to iterate through the items in a collection cannot and should *not* be done inside one of those objects/items. With this in mind, the standard `IDataErrorInfo` interface cannot help with this matter directly. However, it is possible to validate item uniqueness with a small customisation.

The basic idea is to add an `ExternalErrors` property into the data type bass class, or individual data type classes that can be use *from outside the class*. In this way, we can perform our uniqueness check in a view model or wherever your collection property has been defined and feed any errors that arise into the `IDataErrorInfo` interface functionality.

Rather than write out the whole story again, I'd advise you to take a look at an earlier answer that I provided which demonstrates this clearly. Please take a look at my answer to the [Proper validation with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498485/proper-validation-with-mvvm/19499791#19499791) question for more details. If you have any further questions, just let me know.