# Binding Error Validation In Code and not in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I understand how to bind and handle Validation Errors when setting an event in `XAML` as shown below, what I now need to do is Add the same Error Handler but totally in code with no `XAML` as I add the controls at run time in code. I have searched but cannot find anything that point me in the right direction.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Validation.Error="TextBox_Error" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498485/proper-validation-with-mvvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If inderstand you right, here is what you looking for:

```
var element = yourRunTimeControl as DependencyObject;
System.Windows.Controls.Validation.AddErrorHandler(element, ErrorHandler)

private void ErrorHandler(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

You can read more about `Validation.Error` attached event [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validation.error).

Answer (score 1):

You can also set Binding for a control and add ValidationRules for the binding

```
            TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
            txtBox.DataContext = // Your data;

            Binding binding = new Binding();
            binding.Path = // Set path;
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            binding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
            binding.NotifyOnValidationError = true;
            binding.ValidationRules.Add(// Your ValidationRule class);
            txtBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```